# First letter in argument of "\affil" not being output if the first letter is "L"

Tags: macros, document-classes

While trying to add company name in author affiliation, the letter "L" is missing after I compile my LaTeX document.

Demonstration below:

**Latex:**

```
\documentclass{IEEEmce}
\makeatletter
\def\footnoterule{\relax%
  \kern-5pt
  \hbox to \columnwidth{\hfill\vrule width 0.8\columnwidth height 0.4pt\hfill}
  \kern4.6pt}
\makeatother

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{times, amsmath}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcommand{\eg}{\mbox{{\em e.g.}}}
\newcommand{\ie}{\mbox{{\em i.e.}}}
\newcommand{\etal}{\mbox{{\em et al.}}}

\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage{siunitx} 
% \usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{redcolor}{rgb}{1, 0, 0}

%\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

\usepackage[colorlinks,urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}

\usepackage{upmath}

\jvol{XX}
\jnum{XX}
\paper{8}
\jmonth{xxx/xxx}
\publisheddate{00 xxxx 0000}
\currentdate{00 xxxx 0000}
\jname{IEEE Consumer Electronics Magazine}
\pubyear{2023}
\doiinfo{MCE.2023.Doi Number}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\begin{document}
\title{Bla bla}
\author{First Last}
\affil{Lockheed Martin, USA}
\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\enlargethispage{10pt}

\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

Compiled result:

```
First Last
ockheed Martin, USA
```

Can anyone please advise?

Comment: There is nowhere near enough information to be able to answer this sadly. Could you edit into your question a small example of code that can be compiled please?

Comment: Please edit your posting to provide a [compilable minimal example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that), starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, that generates the problem behavior you wish to fix. Do also state how or where the `\affil` macro is defined.

Comment: Thank you. I have provided now a minimal compilable example.

Comment: The `IEEEmce` document class can be found here: https://de.overleaf.com/latex/templates/ieee-consumer-electronics-magazine-template/xphtjrbwmvrz

Comment: @JasperHabicht, I am using the same one.

Comment: @JamesT Maybe keep the `Overleaf` tag in this case since the document class in question is stored in the Overlead document class repository. But of the other hand you are right: The problem here has nothing to do with Overleaf as such.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, there is a bug in the document class `IEEEmce` (which can be found via the [this link](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/ieee-consumer-electronics-magazine-template/xphtjrbwmvrz)). I actually do not recommend using this document class, as it seems not to adhere to best practices when it comes to coding .cls files. At least after having quickly looked at the header of the file, I got the impression that someone has customized another.cls file in a sloppy way, since relevant macros such as `\ProvidesClass` have been kept unchanged and do not match the new file name.

Anyways, let's look at the bug: In the file `IEEEmce.cls` at lines 3411 and 3412, the macros `\affilfont` and `\affil` are defined as follows:

```
\def\affilfont{\reset@font\fontfamily{\sfdefault}\fontsize{9.5}{12}\selectfont\ifodd\c@page\else\leftskip-60pt\fi\rightskip0pc plus1fill}
\def\affil#1{{\par\affilfont#1\par\vskip6pt}}
```

But the definition of `\affilfont` should end with `\relax` or something similar, because otherwise problems will occur if another letter `L` (capital letter or not does not matter) follows.

How can this be a problem? Well, let's assume, you type `\affil{Lockheed Martin, USA}`. This will then expand to

```
{\par\reset@font\fontfamily{\sfdefault}\fontsize{9.5}{12}\selectfont\ifodd\c@page\else\leftskip-60pt\fi\rightskip0pc plus1fillLockheed Martin, USA\par\vskip6pt}
```

And now you have a length of `1fillL` (or `1filll`) which indeed is a valid length (unit) for infinite glue in TeX (for length units, it is irrelevant whether capital letters are used or not). Thus, TeX will interpret this letter `L` as part of the length unit and therefore not typeset this letter.

You can circumvent this bug by typing `\affil{{}Lockheed Martin, USA}` instead.

Comment: The class file indeed looks a mess, identifying itself as `IEEEcsmag`, `IEEEtran` and `IEEEphot` in different places, but never `IEEEmce`. It implements the same bug in `\author` too.

Comment: Wow! worked like a magic. Thanks for explaining it so thoroughly. I guess they should update their IEEEmce.cls file to resolve it.